The StringMap table from Dataverse is not available via MS Dynamics 365
We are utilising Dataverse to extract data from MS Dynamics365, but the StringMap table isn't available from DBO schema. We required this to match the option-sets.
The documentation referred for setting this up: Link
Have connected to the tables via MS SQL server, dataverse and couldn't find the StringMaps table.

is dbo.FilteredStringMap available?

Have you checked the choicelabels table?
select *
from dbo.choicelabels


I believe the underlying table name is: StatusMapBase
The view FilteredStringMap should be there as well as a view call dbo.StringMap

Thank, but the table StatusMapBase, and the view dbo.StringMap aren't available upon checking this.
